# Rest doc for PUT request with request param but without request body setting content type as form url encoded

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restdocs

I have noticed that rest doc `(HttpRequestSnippet.java)` is setting `APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE` as content type for `PUT` with request parameter and without request body. This should be corrected, may be introducing a `MEDIATYPE` as `NONE` and set content type as `NONE` or `ALL` when request body/content empty.
For example, my put request is like below:

```
/api/v1/config/?mode=unknow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a bug in Spring REST Docs' `HttpRequestSnippet` for which I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/763).